# Test for Attributes From Within the Code of Other Attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Is it possible to test for the existence of an attribute within the code of another attribute?

Say you have the following class definition:

```
public class Inception {
    [Required]
    [MyTest]
    public int Levels { get; set; }
}
public class MyTestAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    public override bool IsValid(object o){
        // return whether the property on which this attribute
        // is applied also has the RequiredAttribute
    }
}
```

... is it possible for MyTestAttribute.IsValid to determine whether Inception.Levels has the RequiredAttribute?

Comment: Ooooh! Good one! I'm guessing no, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specific case of a `ValidationAttribute` it is possible, but you have to use the other `IsValid` overload that has a context parameter. The context can be used to get the containing type and also get the name of the property that the attribute is applied to.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
  ValidationContext validationContext)
{
  var requiredAttribute = validationContext.ObjectType
    .GetPropery(validationContext.MemberName)
    .GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
}
```